# Write a js expression inside laravel blade template

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, bootstrap-tags-input

I am using tagsinput for some tagging operation. I want to add some default value to the tag field that is sent from controller. But it seems that the way i am trying to use the js expression is not working. Can anyone help me. Here is code.

```
<script>
    var cities = new Bloodhound({
                    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('text'),
                    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                    local: members
                });
                cities.initialize();
    var elt = $('#researcher');
                elt.tagsinput({
                    itemValue: 'value',
                    itemText: 'text',
                    allowDuplicates: false,
                    typeaheadjs: {
                        name: 'cities',
                        displayKey: 'text',
                        source: cities.ttAdapter()
                    }
                });
    @foreach ($memberResearch->member as $member)
         {!! $text = $member->firstName." ".$member->lastName !!}
         {!! $id = $member->member_id !!}
         @if($member->pivot->role == "Researcher")
             elt.tagsinput('add' , {"value" : {{ $id }} , "text" :{{ $text }} });
         @endif
    @endforeach 
</script>
```

Comment: PHP execute before JS

Comment: Then what should be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP and Javascript are two very seperate entities.

For this kind of stuff, the best approach is for laravel to dump the contents (the data) into the page somewhere where the frontend (javascript) can then pick up.

For example:

```
    // controller
    $appConfig = [ 'foo' => 'bar' ];

    // blade
    <script>
        var AppConfig = {!! ! empty($appConfig) ? json_encode($appConfig) : "{}" !!};
    </script>

    // js
    var foo = JSON.parse(AppConfig).foo;
    console.log(foo); // outputs bar
```

Comment: Yes, yes you should

Comment: I mean should i assign the php data to a js variable and then use that?

Comment: Yes. Alternatively, you can set up an API for your frontend to consume, which is what you would do in larger applications. But for simple data passing, dumping the data in the blade, then picking it back up in js is the way to go. You could also use something like: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I had tried that approach of using JavaScript Service provider. But it is showing me an error "JavaScript not found". Can you please tell me anything about this error.

Comment: If you have chosen to use that library, and you can't get that to work - that would warrant a new question. My example above should give you enough to do it without the JeffreyWay lib - in fact, in the background, its' essentially doing the same thing

Comment: I have also tried your example it still does not work

Comment: Dude - people are going out of their way to help you. At least make an effort and explain on *how* its not working.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and help. I actually did not understand your example completely. There was still some php data i did not dumped that was the reason it did not worked. But after that i have dumped all the data into js variable and it worked as you have said. Thanks :)